# Change the alpha value of the navigation bar item in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

In ViewDidAppear, I have changed the alpha value of the navigation bar to 0.15, but the right navigation bar item became almost invisible as well.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.15
```

Is it possible to change the transparency/alpha value of the right navigation bar item so that it is fully visible (alpha = 1) while having the navigation bar itself be 0.15?

Comment: The `barItems` within the `navigationBar` are part of that `navigationBar`'s layer. When you change the main layer, it effects all sublayers contained within it. Have you tried changing the `navigationBar`'s color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the alpha of the entire bar to 0.15. You should be setting only the `barTintColor` attribute of it to a color with an alpha of 0.15 like so:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yourColorGoesHere().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.15)`

Answer (score 0):

The property changed in Swift 4.0 and is now:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.15)
```

Just substitute black for whatever color you want.

Comment: not working on my navigation bar with a searchbar inside